# php mysql and javascript conflict in loading

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, dictionary, conflict

I'm unable to retrieve from my phpMyAdmin database using php code while i load the map api which uses javascript.

It only load the map javascript. I have some data stored in my database. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

The end result must be both(my database data & the map api) able to load at the same time onto the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Routes Available</th>
    <th>Map Direction</th>
    <th>Preferred Routes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="sidebar">
      <form name="form1" method="get" action="" onSubmit  = "getDirections( this.from.value, this.to.value, this.mode.value ); return false;">
        <p>
          <label style="width:50px;display:inline-block;">From:</label>
          <input type="text" size="34" name="from" value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label style="width:50px;display:inline-block;">To:</label>
          <input type="text" size="34" name="to" value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label style="width:50px;display:inline-block;">Via:</label>
          <select disabled name="mode" disabled>
          <option value="c">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Directions"  style="margin-left:25px"/>
        </p>
      </form>
      <?php
    //PHP CODE STARTS HERE
     if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $db_name="carpool";

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

    $from=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['from']);
    $to=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['to']);

    $query_for_result=mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM routedetails
    WHERE `from` LIKE '%".$from."%'
    AND `to` LIKE '%".$to."%'
    ");

    echo "<table border=1 width=510>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<h2>From: Search Results</h2><ol>";
    $data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result);
    while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result))
    {
        echo "<li>";
        foreach($data_fetch as $row => $value){
            echo "$row - $value<br />";
                }
        echo "</li><hr/>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "</ol>";

    mysql_close();
    }

    ?>
      <div></td>
    <td><div id="map" style="width:600px;height:600px;margin-right:20px;float:left;"></div></td>
    <td><div id="panel"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gothere.sg/jsapi?sensor=false"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
            gothere.load("maps");
            //var directions;
            function initialize() {
                if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                    // Create the Gothere map object.
                    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                    // Set the center of the map.
                    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(1.362083, 103.819836), 11);
                    // Add zoom controls on the top left of the map.
                    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
                    // Add a scale bar at the bottom left of the map.
                    map.addControl(new GScaleControl());


                    // directions.load("from: Changi Airport to: Orchard Road");
                  }
                  directions = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("panel"));
            }

            function getDirections(from, to, mode) {
                var travelMode;

                directions.load("from: " + from + " to: " + to, {travelMode: travelMode});
            }

            gothere.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
        </script></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid html code, you are opening your ordered list `<ol>` inside a cell `<td><h2>...</h2><ol>`, but closing it outside table `</table></ol>`, and you are closing your cell after your row `</tr></td>`. Your output code *currently* looks like this -

```
<table border=1 width=510>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <h2>From: Search Results</h2>
          <ol>
            <li>$row - $value<br /></li>
            <hr/>
   </tr>
      </td>
</table>
         </ol>
```

Also, try removing `$data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result);` as it is a duplicate of the next line `while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result))`

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I have removed $data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result); but it still doesn't work the way I want(it only load the map api). But it doesn't query from my database to list out the result.

Comment: I'm suspecting that this is the part which it loads the onSubmit instead of the method="get"

    <form name="form1" method="get" action=""  onSubmit="getDirections(this.from.value, this.to.value, this.mode.value); return false;">

Comment: since you are using `return false;` in `onSubmit`, the page will not reload, and so the php code will not be executed. You will either need to submit the page, and change how you are calling `getDirections()`, or use ajax to execute php code and insert into the page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sean. But that was the suggested api. After changing something in it, it just fail to load... Any idea how to change it?